# Android Room Complex Queries

Tags: android-room

All the examples I've seen show a simple selection `"SELECT * from user"`. But we all know in the real world we will have queries like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) QTD_MY_PENDING_SO FROM ( SELECT IFNULL((SELECT count(1) FROM (SELECT s.customer_code, s.so_prefix, ... continuing with many lines.
```

That's the reason why we use `rawQuery` from DB on SQLite to select columns from many tables.

So, my question is, how do we make complex queries that will return columns from many tables in Room?

Comment: Room supports `rawquery` Have you checked https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RawQuery

Comment: I will check this. Thanks.